# First compilation of Fortran 90 with flang in FreeBSD 12

Tags: fortran, freebsd, llvm-clang, flang

I am trying to get a 'hello world' type program compiled in FreeBSD 12 with flang.

This is my source code:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
  INTEGER :: X

  PRINT *, "Please, enter a number"
  READ (*, *) X
  PRINT *, "The square root of ", X, " is ", SQRT(X)
END PROGRAM MAIN
```

I try to compile it without success using:

```
$ flang -o test test.f90
/usr/local/bin/ld: /tmp/test-8e54ee.o: in function `MAIN_':
/usr/home/user/test/test.f90:6: undefined reference to `sqrt_'
/usr/local/bin/ld: /usr/local/flang/lib/libflangrti.so: undefined reference to `backtrace_symbols'
/usr/local/bin/ld: /usr/local/flang/lib/libflangrti.so: undefined reference to `backtrace'
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It has been a long time since last time I used Fortran and it is definitively the first time I try to compile it with FreeBSD. Any help/hint is welcomed.

Comment: Don't use flang.  Install gfortran and be happy.

Comment: @evets as FreeBSD does not use gcc but clang I thought flang is the natural way to use Fortran. I am definitively looking to find a way to use Fortran in FreeBSD, if I install gcc, wouldn’t that interfere with clang?

Comment: gcc does not interfere with clang.  Install ports/lang/gcc8 or ports/lang/gcc9.  You'll get either gfortran8 or gfortran9.  The number is the major version number.  I have versions 6, 7, 8, 9, and trunk on my system.  All work fine.

Comment: @M.E. `flang` was an early attempt at making a Fortran compiler for LLVM.  It has been abandoned long ago and should not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the first problem ("undefined reference to sqrt_") by declaring `X` as

```
REAL :: X
```

This makes sense, because `SQRT` in Fortran is defined for real numbers (otherwise it is not clear what `KIND` the returned `REAL` result would have), so flang does not resolve the call and expects that it is a reference to your own custom function defined somewhere else in the code.

As for the second problem ("undefined reference to backtrace_symbols"), this seems to me as a mess in installation. I have just installed a clean FreeBSD 12 into VirtualBox and the linker is in "/usr/bin/ld", and this is where it is looked for by flang, as apparent from the verbose output:

```
$ flang -o test test.f90
(...)
 "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /libexec/ld-elf.so.1 (... etc ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jacob, regarding the second issue, I did not understand if you are suggesting that my installation might be messed up or it is FreeBSD 12 the one that does not work. I cand find `ld` in `/usr/loca/bin/ld`, `/usr/local/x86_64-portbld-freebsd12.0/bin/ld` and `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: I mean that a clean fresh installation of FreeBSD 12 does not seem to have `ld` elsewhere than in `/usr/bin/ld`. So it seems that you have something extra installed (maybe GNU `ld`?), which clashes with the system LLVM `ld`.

Comment: It seems I already got gcc8 installed, and it seems it is a requirement for py36 (which I need)